# Use nested static class as ActionListener for the Outer class

Tags: java, actionlistener, static-members, nested-class

I want to use an nested static class as an `actionListener` for the enclosing class's GUI elements.
I did something like this:

```
public class OuterClass {

    public static void myImplementation() {
        OuterClass.StartupHandler startupHandler = new OuterClass.StartupHandler();
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(startupHandler); // error Line
    }

    public static class StartupHandler implements ActionListener {

   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

        if (e.getSource() == exitMenuItem) {
            System.exit(1);
        } else if (e.getSource() == helpMenuItem) {
            // show help menu
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I invoke this code I get the `NullPointerException` at the //error Line.
Is this the right method to do do this or there is something I did am missing?

Comment: Looks like `exitMenuItem` variable has `null` value when calling your `myImplementation` method. Use a debugger to fix this issue in your code.

Comment: I agree with @LuiggiMendoza There is no point in asking a question for `NullPointerException` get a debugger and debug it. You can use this knowledge in future also.Every day there are so many questions about `NPE`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Aaahhh.... exitMEnuItem was not initialized. That was a silly mistake by me. I will take care of these things now on.Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `exitMenuItem` being initialised? I bet it is `null`.

If you include more of the class (such as where you declared `exitMenuItem`) we'll pin point the problem more easily.

Comment: Thanx. exitMEnuItem was not initialized. That was just a silly mistake by me. Thanx again.